# Objects in Ind-category are filtered colimits of compact subobjects

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits, monoidal-categories

In his paper 'Categories Tensorielles' in section 2.2 Deligne states that if in a tensor category $\mathcal{A}$ all objects are of finite length, then every object of the Ind-category $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ is the filtered colimit of its subobjects that lie in $\mathcal{A}$. Can somebody explain to me why this is true? Deligne does not give any argumentation or proof.

Since the paper is written in Frech and I am not the best translator, here is the original text:

'(2.1.1): tout objet de A est de longueur finie, et d’apres 1.1, les $\text{Hom}(X,Y)$ sont donc de dimension finie sur k.[...] L’hypothese (2.1.1) assure que la sous-categorie $\mathcal{A}$ de $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ est stable par sous-quotients et que tout objet de $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$ est limite inductive filtrante de ses sous-objets dans $\mathcal{A}$.'

Comment: Have a look at the chapter on Indization in "Categories and sheaves" by Kashiwara - Schapira.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Is there a specific result in this book that will be of use? After a quick look I could not find anything.

Comment: Well, first are you aware that every object of $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{A})$ is a filtered colimit of objects in $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg That is that way I would define objects in $\text{Ind}\mathcal{A}$.